# Peersim extra code

Tags: p2p, peer

Where do I find the peersim-extras source code?
I cannot find here. http://peersim.sourceforge.net/

Thanks, Felipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CVS client, for Windows (TortoiseCVS) or Linux, and insert the following command:

**cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@peersim.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/peersim co -P extras**

It is reported on the page you referred to.